# c# console.readline statement 'not working' within a function

Tags: c#, console-application

```
public static void EquipSlot1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Choose a weapon for slot 1:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Sword");
        public int Slot1Choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   }
```

In the above code, I am not able to place the '}' after the console.readline statement to close the function. A red squiggly line appears after the second writeline statement, and when I do place the '}' after the readline statement, it takes it to be the closing of the class and not the function. so I assumed that for some reason the readline function isn't allowed inside the function. Am I doing something wrong? And additionally, what other forms of input can I have within a function if a readline statement isn't allowed?

Comment: Remove `public`

Comment: local variables cannot have access modifiers.

Comment: public, private, sealed and so on can only be used for classes

Comment: public is the culprit.
public int Slot1Choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); chage to 
 int Slot1Choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: @BjörnKarpenstein  I hope you are joking

Comment: @Striter Alfa: .. i mean for Global Class Variables and Class Functions, but not within Class Functions is correct. I was too fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the title, this is not an issue with the `Console.WriteLine` the cause of error is the public declaration scoped inside a method. such  public declarations are not allowed inside the method, if we declare a variable inside any method means it's scope is limited to that particular method. so we are not permitted to re-define the [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) of a public variable, so it would be  like the following:

```
public int Slot1Choice=0;
public static void EquipSlot1()
{
     Console.WriteLine("Choose a weapon for slot 1:");
     Console.WriteLine("1. Sword");
     Slot1Choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the public access modifier on the method.

A variable declared inside a method body has the scope of the method and cannot be public.

Replace your code with:

```
static int Slot1Choice;

public static void EquipSlot1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Choose a weapon for slot 1:");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Sword");
    Slot1Choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```